# Quicksight Athena - [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am getting below error when i am trying to create New Dataset in Quicksight from Athena. I tried for "Table" and "view". It gives below error :

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client.

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403;
 Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 4X60ASZS5T2Q0A9C; S3 Extended Request ID:
(Path: s3://metadataitcfcontrol/) [Execution ID: a07d4718-ffae-40b7-9777-688399fbb56f]
```

Seeing the error message i understand problem is w.r.t access on S3 bucket, but how to fix it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this by adding S3 bucket permission in the QuickSight console.

Go to:

Manage QuickSight -> Security & permissions -> Add or remove -> In S3 -> Details -> Select the bucket you want to query -> Update

Comment: This link was helpful for me https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-permission-errors/

Comment: I don't have add or remove section. Maybe because I am using standard Quicksight and not Enterprise?

Comment: I needed to grant permission using the method from Aswin for a bucket I never created called aws-athena-query-results-us-east-1-<accountnumber> even though I never created this bucket and my Athena results were being saved to another bucket. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was working with the Athena Data Connector behind my data catalog, I had to provide the Quicksight (default role) access for invoking Lambda (InvokeFunction).